# How to stop Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, dism, sfc

I have a Windows Server 2026 that executes `Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` now for more than one day.

This task is executed by TiWorker.exe. I read that it is not save to terminate the TiWorker.exe and it may leave may system in an unstable state.

- The dism command runs now for more than 48h and stuck at 10%.
- It is a virtual server. 1 CPU us running the whole time for the TiWorker.exe 4GB of ram is in use. The machine has currently 10GB available memory. (Used are currently 6.8GB, so there is enough memory).
- Internet connection is fast an stable.
- The cbs.log is still growing and data is written to it. Size is now at 257MB
- `sfc /scannow` was executed first and it succeeded without any error messages.
- Latest updates are already installed.
- The machine was just rebooted a few hours before.
- `Dism` with `AnalyzeComponentstore` showed a size of 15GB and sayed that it is useful to execute a `StartComponentCleanup`

I had a case, were a similar machine didn't reboot after terminating this TiWorker and showed after a reboot that I should wait until windows is "Getting Windows Ready Don't Turn off your Computer". I had to recover this server from a backup. Even booting in safemode wasn't possible.

Any idea what to do.

**Edit after 4 days:**
I can see in the CBS.LOG that each KB fix is applied and checked.
Currently the files for KB4598243 (BS-Build 14393.4169) are checked. It takes nearly 1.5h until a OS update is completely checked and verified. Since there are another 35 KBs left, it will take approximately another 3days. The CBS.log just growed to nearly 400MB. Dism creates nearly 35000 lines for each OS update...

**Edit after 7 days:** Still running. Now at 70.7%. Now I see entries after nearly 3 hours. Again I see entries in the CBS log every 3 hours. Always showing a new build number of the Server 2016.When I compare it to the current list I have 75 Builds left. 3 hours each. This means another 9 days... Memory still the same.

```
2023-04-23 21:36:42, Info                  CBS    Reporting package change for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.2848.1.6, curre
2023-04-23 21:36:42, Info                  CBS    SQM: Package change report datapoints not populated because SQM is not initialized or not running online.
2023-04-23 21:36:42, Info                  CBS    Reporting package change completion for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.2848
2023-04-23 21:36:42, Info                  CBS    Overall time performance datapoint is invalid. [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2023-04-23 21:36:42, Info                  CBS    SQM: Package change report datapoints not populated because SQM is not initialized or not running online.
2023-04-24 00:33:20, Info                  CBS    Reporting package change for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.2879.1.6, curre
2023-04-24 00:33:20, Info                  CBS    SQM: Package change report datapoints not populated because SQM is not initialized or not running online.
2023-04-24 00:33:20, Info                  CBS    Reporting package change completion for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.2879
2023-04-24 00:33:20, Info                  CBS    Overall time performance datapoint is invalid. [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2023-04-24 00:33:20, Info                  CBS    SQM: Package change report datapoints not populated because SQM is not initialized or not running online.
2023-04-24 03:32:00, Info                  CBS    Reporting package change for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.2906.1.5, curre
2023-04-24 03:32:00, Info                  CBS    SQM: Package change report datapoints not populated because SQM is not initialized or not running online.
2023-04-24 03:32:00, Info                  CBS    Reporting package change completion for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.2906
2023-04-24 03:32:00, Info                  CBS    Overall time performance datapoint is invalid. [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2023-04-24 03:32:00, Info                  CBS    SQM: Package change report datapoints not populated because SQM is not initialized or not running online.
2023-04-24 06:27:31, Info                  CBS    Reporting package change for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.2941.1.10, curr
2023-04-24 06:27:31, Info                  CBS    SQM: Package change report datapoints not populated because SQM is not initialized or not running online.
2023-04-24 06:27:31, Info                  CBS    Reporting package change completion for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.2941
2023-04-24 06:27:31, Info                  CBS    Overall time performance datapoint is invalid. [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]
2023-04-24 06:27:31, Info                  CBS    SQM: Package change report datapoints not populated because SQM is not initialized or not running online.
```

**EDIT after 14 days:**
Seams that there is no answer. Finally the operations ends after 12 days.

:(

Comment: Basically “Getting Windows Ready” means that it continues the component store cleanup.

Comment: Yes. But if it runs forever? Or some corruption? How to stop this?

Comment: According to the first sentence you are 3 years ahead so 9 days shouldn't really matter. But yeah, maybe restore from backup again if it just keeps going. Not sure who is running the (virtual) server but you may be able to get support to check what the bottleneck is.

Comment: @Gantendo We checked an older backup, without restoring all other data required on this server. It showed that the problem in the system is older than 12 month. Starting `Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` on a 1 year old backup shows the same behaviour. Seams that the component cleanup never ran successful or was never executed. Memory is still available. Still 1 CPU running under 100% all others idle. Hard disk access is available but not exzessive.